# Connecting to Legacy Stored Procedures and Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction please?

I'm working in a VS2013 C# ASP.NET MVC4 application (my first) and I need to connect to and run stored procedures in an existing SQL Server database.

I know that there are loads of documentation/articles out there but, to be honest, I've ended up confusing myself.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: use `SqlCommand` & `SqlConnection` classes from `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace or try using `Enterprise Library Data Access Block`.Read http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440726(v=pandp.60).aspx

Comment: Cheers gents, I'll give that a blast

Comment: Cheers folks got it all sorted :)

Answer (score 3):

Create your SQL connection:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

then create your command - which will be a 'run stored procedure command':

```
var command = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedureName", connection) { 
                       CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure });
```

open your connection

```
connection.Open();
```

Execute the procedure:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Close the connection (you should really replace the above with `using` statements):

```
connection.Close();
```

If your stored procedure returns data, then you will need to use a different `Execute` method.

Comment: Cheer matey, I'll get this a go

Comment: @SLC - wow! you didn't show how to pass a parameter though.Also the call to `SqlCommand` can be wrapped in a `using` block too.

Comment: Cheers folks got it all sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention database is already there. You can pick database first approach. You should use entity framework. Just add an EDMX file in your project and start interacting with the database. You can read more EF (Entity Framework) on the internet.

You can go with ADO.Net if you can not add EDMX in your project. Using EDMX is simple than ADO.Net (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, DataTable, DataSet). But ADO.Net on the other side is a mature technology than EF and have several features which is not in EF.

Comment: Cheers folks got it all sorted :)